# Storybook vite failed to build with ChakraUI / React 18

Tags: storybook, vite, emotion, chakra-ui, react-18

I'm creating a **UI library with Vite and Storybook**. Sadly, the storybook build is **broken**.

In dev mode, i have some error during build, but i can browse storybooks component anyway. But production build failed completely with same error.

#### Here is the error :

```bash
ERROR in ./node_modules/@chakra-ui/icons/node_modules/@chakra-ui/icon/dist/index.esm.js 58:28
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (58:28)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     __css: styles
|   };
>   const _viewBox = viewBox ?? fallbackIcon.viewBox;
|   if (element && typeof element !== "string") {
|     return /* @__PURE__ */ React.createElement(chakra.svg, {
 @ ./node_modules/@chakra-ui/icons/dist/index.esm.js [...lines]
 @ ./node_modules/@chakra-ui/storybook-addon/dist/preset/register.cjs.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/globals/polyfills.js ./node_modules/@storybook/core-client/dist/esm/manager/index.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-links/manager.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-docs/manager.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-controls/manager.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-actions/manager.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-backgrounds/manager.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-viewport/manager.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-toolbars/manager.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-measure/manager.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-outline/manager.js ./node_modules/@storybook/addon-interactions/manager.js ./node_modules/@chakra-ui/storybook-addon/dist/preset/register.cjs.js ./.storybook/generated-refs.js
```

I used latest version of chakra, react 18, emotion 11 and storybook 6.5 with vite builder. I tried with webpack 4 and 5 and it is worse. I search so much solution in chakra ui issues, storybook's ones, but nothing seems to work.

In production, i have some files built, but when serving static folder with http-server, i have a blank alert with "No preview" message from storybook.

##### Here is my package.json :

```json
{...},
"type": "module",
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.18.13",
    "@chakra-ui/storybook-addon": "^4.0.10",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.6.22",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/builder-vite": "^0.2.2",
    "@storybook/jest": "^0.0.10",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.5.10",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.0.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "eslint": "8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.6.4",
    "generate-changelog": "^1.8.0",
    "http-server": "^14.1.1",
    "husky": "8.0.1",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2",
    "vite": "^3.0.9",
    "vite-plugin-dts": "^1.4.1",
    "vite-tsconfig-paths": "^3.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.0.9",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "2.2.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
    "framer-motion": "^7.2.1",
    "nookies": "^2.5.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
},
```

##### And my .storybook/main.cjs :

```js
module.exports = {
  stories: [
    '../packages/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../packages/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
    '../stories/**/*.stories.mdx',
    '../stories/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)',
  ],
  addons: [
    '@storybook/addon-links',
    '@storybook/addon-essentials',
    '@storybook/addon-interactions',
    '@chakra-ui/storybook-addon',
  ],
  framework: '@storybook/react',
  core: {
    builder: '@storybook/builder-vite',
    disableTelemetry: true,
  },
  features: {
    emotionAlias: false,
    storyStoreV7: true,
    modernInlineRender: false,
  },
  reactOptions: {
    legacyRootApi: false,
  },
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

In the [Instalation](https://chakra-ui.com/getting-started) section of Chakra-IU documentation:

> Version 2 of Chakra UI is only compatible with React 18. If you are
> still needing to use React 17 or earlier, please use [version 1 of
> Chakra UI](https://v1.chakra-ui.com/guides/first-steps).

You are using `"react": "^18.2.0"`.
Install the chakra-ui libs with v1.*, this should solve your problem.

Comment: Don't think this is it - OP states they're using `"@chakra-ui/react": "2.2.1"` and `"react": "^18.2.0"` which is a valid combination

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this is due to a lack of support for the `??` [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing).

```bash
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (58:28)
...
>   const _viewBox = viewBox ?? fallbackIcon.viewBox;
                              ^ ~ char 28
```

Note that in Storybook 6.5, there are some core packages which still rely on Webpack 4:

[[Bug]: remove @storybook/*-webpack4 from @storybook/core-server · Issue #20062 · storybookjs/storybook](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/20062)

You might resolve this issue by adding some babel config:

```json
// .babelrc
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will take a look at my babelrc file! Seems like finally storybook v7 will remove webpack 4 dependency thus resolving the problem. Also they have now a full support for vite builder.

Currently I dropped Chakra / emotion for Tailwind / headless ui and already enabled Storybook v7 beta and it’s already better than version 6.